# Is Chrome rounding media query em units wrong?

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I have set up media query break points as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width:48em){
    /* phone */
}
@media screen and (min-width:48.063em){
    /* tablet*/
}
```

I got the 48.063em value from some PX to EM calculator (I was told to use em-units for some reason, but that is outside of this question), and it is working ok in firefox, but in chrome, it seems that browser width of 769px falls BETWEEN those max-width / min-width values, and neither is applied to the page. I know this can be fixed by setting that min-width to 48.01em, don't worry about that. I have seen 48.063em used in some tutorials also.

Can someone confirm if this is a bug in chrome, or an error in my logic?

Comment: `em` can't be transitioned to `px` - it depends on font, font-size, etc. Why you don't want to use `px`, when tablets and phones have viewport defined in px?

Comment: PS. what about devices with width `48.03em`? If you are using so strange equations.

Comment: Isn't 769 pixels equivalent to 48.0625 ems assuming 1 em == 16 pixels? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh my, you are right. I assumed that the px to em calculator would give exact conversion. Lesson learned: Do the math yourself, or at least double-check values. Thanks!

Comment: But it is interesting to note that Firefox does appear to round it differently, as 769px does fall within 48.063em. IE behaves similarly to Chrome, as I would expect. It seems Firefox just rounds values to a much lower precision.

Comment: I was about to comment exactly as you did about firefox, this essentially turns the question around, is there a rounding bug in firefox?

I am a bit unexperienced here in SO, not sure if I should edit, delete or leave the question.. Will it contribute to anything as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact problem and I think you are correct that your width is falling between the specified values and therefore neither style is applied.
I think the solution is to remove your phone media query and just have the phone styles at the top level, like so:

```
/* phone styles */

@media screen and (min-width:48.063em){
    /* tablet styles */
}
```

In this case your phone styles will be applied unless the width is 48.063em or above, in which case the phone styles will be overridden by similar ones in the media query (mobile first design). This way you only have a single cut-off point.
You could further extend this to larger devices in the same way:

```
@media screen and (min-width:100em){
    /* even larger styles */
}
```

If you look at the CSS for [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) you will see this approach, which is what helped me figure it out. Why the original code seems to work in browsers other than Chrome, I do not know.

Comment: Read the comments on the question, you have the same error on the decimals there as I had. .0625 != 0.063