# Bootstrap 4 fixed navbar overlaps body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Now that [nearly] everything is based off `rems`, the navbar seems to have some funky height properties. For one, the navbar height is variable while the padding is a static 8px on top and bottom.

As a result of the navbar's pseudo-dynamic nature, simply setting the body's padding-top to 50px no longer works. If the user changes their font size, the bar height will no longer be 50px.

Has anyone figured out how to give the body an appropriate amount of padding to keep it exactly below the navbar when scrolled to the top of the page?

It seems like a regression if one has to use jQuery to accomplish this, but perhaps that's the only way.

Example code:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 54px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.container-fluid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse container">
  <a href="www.google.com" class="navbar-brand">google.com</a>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <p>I am content that is getting overlapped by the navbar!</p>
</div>
```

Note how the bar overlaps at some font sizes, and there is a gap at other sizes. On Mac OS X you can change font size with command+minus and command+plus

EDIT: I have raised an issue on the bootstrap 4 github page. The bug is confirmed, but it might fall out of scope since they typically don't support zooming effects.

Comment: Hi there, theoretical explanation is of little help for coding questions. Can you post the code that you are working on?

Comment: @ManojKumar example code added with a bit more explanation

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any overlap in Windows 7, Firefox 42. Logically there won't be any with current code.

Comment: @ManojKumar hmm, maybe it is an issue with chrome. When using the chrome inspector and the computed tab, I can clearly see the height of the navbar changing when I increase or decrease the font size.

Comment: I wrapped the code in ja [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/njrnc78c/) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can confirm your issue for chrome. The calculated height of the navbar change when zooming. The preceding results in a gap for zoom levels of 125% and 175%, see below:
[image]

For 125% the calculated height of the navbar = 53.6 (37.6 + 8*2) instead of 54.
Possible related: [Is Chrome rounding media query em units wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577447/is-chrome-rounding-media-query-em-units-wrong)

Comment: I have confirmed that this issue also exists in Safari.